# Compile minted code highlighting on system without minted installed

Tags: minted

I'm currently working with the [*minted package*](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) for source code highlighting.

As the title says, **I'm looking for an option to compile latex code with *minted* content on a system that has not installed the requirements**. I thought of a way of using the already generated files (generated by a system that has *minted* installed).

Unfortunately, I have not found any option to avoid the recompilation. A option to tell *minted* not to call any external programs and just use the already generated files would be great.

---

**The Background**: I need to share my latex files with someone who has not installed *minted* and the required additional software, Pygments.
But the document I have to share heavily uses the package and a switch is not a suitable solution for me.

Is this even possible or do I have to install *minted* on the other system as well?

Comment: the minted user manual suggests options `finaizecache` and `frozencache`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I was looking for!